# Bound for conditional expectation of event $E[X \vert X \leq x]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

So I kind of get stuck on proving the equation 
$$E[X \vert X \leq x]=\frac{E[X 1_{\lbrace X \leq x \rbrace }]}{P(X\leq x)}\leq E[X].$$
So any tips would be appreciated, I still want to figure at least a tiny bit out by myself though :D

Comment: Consider a copy of $X$, that is, another random variable $X'$ independent of $X$ with the same distribution, and note that the random variable $$Y=(X-X')\cdot(\mathbf 1_{X\leqslant x}-\mathbf 1_{X'\leqslant x})$$ is nonpositive everywhere since $$(X-X')\cdot(g(X)-g(X'))\leqslant0$$ for every nonincreasing function $g$. Now, $$E(Y)=2E(X\mathbf 1_{X\leqslant x})-2E(X)P(X\leqslant x)$$ hence you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equality is just a definition: if $\mathbb{P}(A)>0$, then
$$ \mathbb{E}[X\mid A]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[X1_A]}{\mathbb{P}(A)} $$
by definition. Now take $A=\{X\leq x\}$.

To show the inequality, I suggest using the law of total expectation, which tells us that
$$ \mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X\mid A]\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{E}[X\mid A^c]\mathbb{P}(A^c) $$
Taking $A=\{X\leq x\}$ once again, we get
$$ \mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X\mid X\leq x]\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)+\mathbb{E}[X\mid X>x]\mathbb{P}(X>x) $$
and since
$$ \mathbb{E}[X\mid X>x]\geq x\geq \mathbb{E}[X\mid X\leq x]$$ 
it follows that
$$ \mathbb{E}[X\mid X\leq x]\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)+\mathbb{E}[X\mid X>x]\mathbb{P}(X>x)$$
$$\geq \mathbb{E}[X\mid X\leq x](\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)+\mathbb{P}(X>x))=\mathbb{E}[X\mid X\leq x] $$